# import a pd.read_sql() DataFrame from another File to process it further

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, dataframe

I want to import a dataframe from a read_datasets.py file and process it in a main.py. Additionally use a function for the mysql connection.

main.py:

```
    import mysql.connector
    import pandas as pd



def con():
    connection = None
    
    try:
        # declaration of default mysql settings
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="xx",
        user="xx",
        passwd="xx",
        db="xx",
        )
    # If connection is not successful    
    except:
        print("cant connect to database")
        return 0
    
    # if connection is successfull
    print("connected")
    # Making Cursor Object For Query Execution
    cursor = connection.cursor()

if __name__ == '__main__':

  print("actually in main.py")


  #talk to connection mysql
  temp1 = pd.read_sql("SELECT xx FROM xx", con() )
  # filter all NAN Vlaues in the Dataframe
   temp1 = temp1.dropna()
```

in read_datasets.py:

```
import pandas as pd
from main import con

temp1 = pd.read_sql("SELECT xx FROM xx", con)
# filter all NAN Vlaues in the Dataframe
temp1 = temp1.dropna()
```

i got the error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cursor'

Comment: `cursor = connection.cursor()` what is this?

Comment: a cursor that allows me in python to command a database, right ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `temp1 = pd.read_sql("SELECT xx FROM xx", con())` in `read_datasets.py`? (Seems like you forgot to call `con`, it should be `con()` instead of `con`)

Answer (score 0):

I'm only experienced with doing this using SQLAlchemy, so I'll post how to do it using that package:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

def db_connection(self):
    engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://{0}:{1}@{2}:3306/{3}'.format(username, password, host, db_name), echo=False)
    connection = engine.connect()
    return connection
```

^I didn't define the variables for password etc, but note that the code above won't work since you'll need to do that!

You can then call:

```
pd.read_sql("SQL query here", db_connection())
```